DeadlineExceeded Exception while publishing message to GCP Pub sub from Java Springboot app
In Java Springboot app, i'm publishing message to GCP Pub Sub and it is getting failed sometimes with DeadlineExceeded exception. Can someone please advise me on best retry approach.
Publishing message to GCP Pub sub. Below is the code
publisher = Publisher.newBuilder(topicName).build();
            ByteString data = ByteString.copyFromUtf8(message);
            // Invoking the gpsAttrEnrichment in Core lib
            PubsubMessage pubsubMessage = PubsubMessage.newBuilder().setData(data)
                    .putAllAttributes(gpsAttrEnrichment.getOrganizationValue(orgs.get(index),
                            envKey, document, jsonObject))
                    .build();
            ApiFuture<String> messageIdFuture = publisher.publish(pubsubMessage);
            String messageId = messageIdFuture.get();
            ContentBasedRouterProcessor.log.info("Published message ID: " + messageId);


What percentage of requests are returning a deadline exceeded? And in what context does this code live? Is this just a simplification or is it actually the case that a new publisher client is being created for each message and then the code is waiting for the response on each request individually?
